# How can I retrieve the current best solution from the Gurobi solver when using PulP?

Tags: python, gurobi, pulp

If I use the interactive solver in the gurobi solver, I can do the following:

```
gurobi> m = read('model.mp')
gurobi> m.optimize()
[...]
Found heuristic solution: objective 821425.00000
```

Then abort and get the current solution via

```
gurobi> m.printAttr('X')
```

I want to have the same behavior in pulp. In particular, after having called:

```
prob =  pulp.LpProblem(name="MIPProblem", sense=pulp.LpMaximize)
[...]
status = prob.solve(pulp.GUROBI_CMD(msg=True, keepFiles=1))
```

I want to wait until the first heuristic solution is found/abort after a certain timespan and then obtain the current best solution found by Gurobi. How would I do that?

Comment: Is ```prob.objective``` works? I think you should remove ```status = ``` part and try to solve solely then get the answer with ```prob.objective```

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you look at the docs for `pulp.solvers` - https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/solvers.html you can set either a time limit, or an allowable optimality gap. To stop at the first feasible solution, set a very large optimality gap.

Comment: @kabdulla But can I for example, every t amount of time print the current best solution, and else resume solving to get a better one (repeating this until I get the best one)? If I set a time limit or optimality gap, but then call .solve() again, it starts from scratch, does it?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `pulp.GUROBI` or `pulp.GUROBI_CDM`.
The main difference is that `pulp.GUROBI` is a wrapper to **gurobipy** (the Gurobi Python Interface) while `pulp.GUROBI_CDM` uses the command line (i.e, it writes the LP/ILP in a file and then calls the solver).

Let's distinguish the two cases:

- **Case 1**: `pulp.GUROBI`:

  In this case you can access the solverModel object. For the fields you can     refer directly to the documentation. However, for your specific use case what you're looking for is [ObjBound](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/objbound.html).
  A Small Example:

  ```
  import pulp

  ...

  status = prob.solve(pulp.GUROBI(timeLimit=1))

  print(pulp.LpStatus[status]) # status

  print(prob.solverModel.ObjBound) # best objective found
  ```
- **Case 2**: `pulp.GUROBI_CDM`:

  In this case, the problem is solved by command line and the solution is read from the result file (i.e., [here](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/blob/c3f728c3a1ad3ac7f765feb45fb3483d1a5080d8/pulp/solvers.py#L2073))

  ```
  import pulp

  ...

  status = prob.solve(pulp.GUROBI_CMD(options=[('TimeLimit','1')]))

  print(pulp.LpStatus[status]) # status

  print(pulp.value(prob.objective)) # best objective found
  ```

  Note that, *GUROBI_CMD does provide good solution status* [[see here]](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/blob/c3f728c3a1ad3ac7f765feb45fb3483d1a5080d8/pulp/solvers.py#L2080), so you may read Optimal even though the solution is not since no information about the status are provided by the Gurobi solution file.